# Publish Jenkins Job build status to Gitlab commit from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm new to jenkins. I'm using Jenkins 2.77 and GitLab Enterprise Edition 9.5.5. I see a strange issue happening.

I've created 3 Jenkins freestyle jobs and have built a pipeline view for those jobs *[1 ~> 2 ~> 3]*. I am able to trigger builds with Gitlab webhook and publish the status of job 3 to Gitlab without any issues . All these were done manually.

I have to create these 3 jobs for about 100 projects. So I chose to generate these jobs via jenkins job DSL. I am able to generate the jobs and build a pipeline view. Also triggering the builds (for a particular project) from Gitlab webhook works fine. In the pipeline view I am able to see the builds too. But unfortunately due to some reason, I'm not getting feedback to Gitlab.

The strange thing I observed is, if open the "job 3" in jenkins and just click save without even changing anything, it auto-magically sends the feedback from the next builds.

I've no clue what is going on.

**DSL of job 3:**

```
job("SyntaxCheck") {

logRotator {
    numToKeep(10)
    artifactNumToKeep(10)
}
parameters {
    stringParam('jobType', '')
}
scm {
  git  {
    remote {
      url('gitlab url to checkout the project')
      branch('master')
      credentials(*********)
      extensions {
        submoduleOptions {
          recursive(true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
steps {
  shell(puppetparser)
}
publishers {
  gitLabCommitStatusPublisher {
    name('syntaxcheck')
    markUnstableAsSuccess(false)
  }
}
}
```

Suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: Compare the generated job's config.xml with the manually create config.xml. And post any differences.

Comment: @daspilker infact there was a difference I could spot which was the cause of the issue. Thanks for pointing to that.